# Reset Window for EWM in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, window, exponential

I’m trying to calculate the ewm using the following pandas dataframe:

|  | Parameter | new_file | EWM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 495.56912 | 0 | 495.569120 |
| 1 | 494.51257 | 1 | 495.505727 |
| 2 | 493.65040 | 1 | 495.394407 |
| 3 | 492.95905 | 1 | 495.248286 |
| 4 | 492.31470 | 1 | 495.072271 |
| 5 | 491.66367 | 0 | 491.663670 |
| 6 | 491.05520 | 1 | 494.639001 |
| 7 | 490.38733 | 1 | 494.383901 |

What I want is for the window to reset every time the value in the ‘new_file’ column is 0. This dataframe is created from multiple input files and every time the new_file column is 0 it represents the start of a new file. As such I don’t want the EWM to calculate using the last value of the previous input file, I need it to reset.

My code to create the EWM column is as follows:

```
  df['EWM'] = np.where(df[‘new_file’] ==1, df['Parameter'].ewm(alpha=0.06,adjust=False).mean() , df['Parameter'])
```

You can probably see from the dataframe extract above that the 6th row that is calculated isn’t what it should be if that were to be start of a new window. It should produce the values below (which I obtained from excel):

|  | Parameter | new_file | EWM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 495.56912 | 0 | 495.5691 |
| 1 | 494.51257 | 1 | 495.5057 |
| 2 | 493.6504 | 1 | 495.3944 |
| 3 | 492.95905 | 1 | 495.2483 |
| 4 | 492.3147 | 1 | 495.0723 |
| 5 | 491.66367 | 0 | 491.6637 |
| 6 | 491.0552 | 1 | 491.6272 |
| 7 | 490.38733 | 1 | 491.5528 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a boolean mask to check for the start of new file, then calculate the cumulative sum on this mask to identify the blocks of rows that belong to same file, then `group` the `Parameter` column on these blocks and calculate the exponential weighted average

```
b = df['new_file'].eq(0).cumsum()
df['EWM'] = df['Parameter'].groupby(b, group_keys=False)\
                           .ewm(alpha=0.06, adjust=False).mean()
```

---

```
   Parameter  new_file         EWM
0  495.56912         0  495.569120
1  494.51257         1  495.505727
2  493.65040         1  495.394407
3  492.95905         1  495.248286
4  492.31470         1  495.072271
5  491.66367         0  491.663670
6  491.05520         1  491.627162
7  490.38733         1  491.552772
```

Comment: Thanks. Although i get the following message when I try it.    

                                     "AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'ewm' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try 
       using the 'apply' method"

Comment: @Mark Try upgrading  `pandas`